# ¿Cómo limitar login a un usuario SessionScoped por sesión en jsf?

Tags: jsf, login, session, sesiones, scope

Estoy desarrollando un aplicativo de resolución de incidentes en jsf2.0 y bdd postgres, las características principales ya la tengo listas pero requiero que el usuario solo pueda ingresar una sola vez. Estaba usando un arreglo de tipo static en mi controlador @SessionScoped para controlarlo pero al controlar así, si se va la luz o cierran el explorador sin dar en logout queda registrado que ese usuario está logueado. ¿Existe alguna forma de relacionar un @SessionScoped con el usuario y listar los sesion scope activos y que usuario pertenece a cada uno?, o si alguien tiene una sugerencia respecto al tema sería de mucha ayuda.

Comment: ¿Usas Primefaces o Richfaces?

Answer (score 0):

Es una tecnica realmente dificil, ya que si quieres solo una sesión, pero el usuario cierra su explorador, debe esperar a que la misma caduque para poder volver a entrar, por otro lado te recomiendo quitar el campo estático y usar la anotación `@Singleton` que es para usar la misma instancia en todos lados donde se inyecta, además de agregar un las anotaciones Lock `@Read` y `@Write` para evitar problemas de concurrencia.

Aunque creo la mejor solución de todas sigue siendo permitir el ingreso múltiple, ya que hay muchos casos donde todo se volverá más confuso (que pasa si se cierra el browser y pierde los datos de sesión, que pasa si abre otra pestaña, que pasa si entra desde el teléfono en una red 3g y cambia a wifi...)

Answer (score 0):

podrías usar Servlet 3.x el cual puedes controlar los inicios de sesiones y así controlarlos con detalle
Necesitas el formulario algo así:

EL controlador en general se tendría algo como sigue:

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
@SessionScoped
public class LoginController implements Serializable {
@Inject
private MainDao dao;
@ManagedProperty("#{loginManager.logins}")
private Set<Person> logins;
private String nickname;
private String clave;
private Person p;
//g+s+
public String Login() {
FacesContext context=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
try {
    request.login(nickname, clave);//si existe error en el login salta el 
    //error y no permite que se loguee otra vez
    p=dao.validarLogin(this.getNickname(), this.getClave());
    if(p!=null) {
       if(!logins.contains(p){
         logins.add(p);
         return "pagina?faces-redirect=true"
       }
    }
}catch(ServletException e) {
    ......
}
return null;
}
}
```

En realidad no es necesario el `logins`, este en el caso de que se requiera tener un control de los usuarios conectados basta con que en `request.login(nickname, clave)` salte el error no avanzara de nuevo a loguearse.